# Firebase Scalability

Tags: ios, database, firebase, structure, scalability

I'd like to develop an iOS App where you're able to find nearby people and chat with them. However, I don't know how firebase handles a lot of data.

Example: 
So, IF the App has 100k users. And a lot of them are always chatting, searching for nearby people, could firebase actually handle that amount of requests and posts? If not, how do you use firebase then? Does that depend on the structure I build? I appreciate each answer that can help me to decide whether to use it or not :)

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Though its a pretty broad question but I will catch one of your specificity of scalability.  Firebase is a NoSQL Database which imports and exports database in JSON format. One of the key factors to it being a perfect BAAS is its ability to handle transactions or in-built commands to save and retrieve data in almost hassle free way.

Not only these, but features such as easy-integration of AdMob, Push Notifications, Remote Config add to its perfect DNA Structure. Not to forget that its Storage uses Google Cloud Bucket. So, yes pretty trust-able in terms of infrastructure.

- Check out all features [here.](https://firebase.google.com/features/)

Firebase has grown to be a big name. If we think about the scale in terms of popularity, check out these clients:

[Customers At Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/customers/)

- Booking.com
- Viber
- Asus
- Domain
- Glow... and many more big names.

Also,

In recent Google I/0 2016, there was a big focus on Firebase's extension as BAAS. You might be interested to see these videos:

- [Zero to App: Develop with Firebase - Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE)
- [Recipes for App Development with Firebase](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGuL_P7PvNAhVCs48KHQcLAmIQtwIIKzAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBftyfmILbrM&usg=AFQjCNF0BiIP8_mb5eYqD4P-SXrAOHziAg&sig2=0vHsVJIxTf2hWcfsg3PUyQ)

At the end, scalability has a vital factor of a well-planned structured database. Good luck on that!

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to make something that needs to be highly scalable on Firebase be prepared for a trial by fire. Most companies that say they have some sort of Firebase integration generally use it for smaller issues rather than one of that technical nature. It's nature can serve to bite you if you aren't wary of it.

Take for example retrieving messages for a chat. How do you store these messages? Firebase suggests you do so flatly. So do that. Now how do you assign these messages to multiple on going chats? You need to list what messages belong to each chat. But since your messages are flat you now have to do a **query for each individual message**. In a large application - making countless database queries every second can be dangerous. To address this problem, you could place the messages under the channel itself, and then just mass retrieve them by sorting by date.

Basically, you'll find a lot of issues like this. It's because Firebase was designed to be **simple**, while real time applications can often become **complex**.

Another downside is Firebase is quite expensive versus a traditional database, and if you're serving a lot of customers this can be quite a detriment.

Comment: Reading through Ramzi answer. You can now use Firebase `Firestore` service which allows you to have a collections and a collections of collections - means it's no longer needed to be all flat.